# how to convert digital signal(PWM) into analog signal

Tags: pwm

analog signal can b easily made by using PWM in micrcontroller but it is not a real analog signal. please tell me how can i convert PWM into real analog signal

Comment: Low Pass Filter.

Comment: How accurate and how stable?

Comment: How quick PWM and what signal bandwidth do you require?

Comment: actully i want to make air mouse using accelerometer and Arduino for this i modified my joystick. I removed the potentiometer and give signal from Arduino which use PWM according to accelerometer signal. but it is not a analog signal so computer curser vibrate

Comment: No attempt to search for relevant information. Question should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you actually attempt to search, at all?:

[On StackExchange (possibly the most complete answer to any PWM to V question to be conceived and top of the search list)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34843/how-determine-the-rc-time-constant-in-pwm-digital-to-analog-low-pass-filter?rq=1)

OR

[On instructables if you want it simpler and less broadly explained.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Analog-Output-Convert-PWM-to-Voltage/)

OR

[On Google Images even](https://www.google.nl/search?q=convert%20PWM%20to%20analog&espv=2&biw=1349&bih=876&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=l9ySVYXDCYuqsQHrtojoAQ&ved=0CCAQsAQ)

The options are limitless for getting this exact information.